# Can we show javascript confirmation box on onsubmit of wicket ajax button method 

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5

Can we append script to show first a yes\no confirmation  popup and then if user selects yes then proceed for the save logic

Note: i want confirmation popup within onsubmit of button 
like

```
protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {
  yes\no confirmation 
  depends on choice move for next logic ......
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This [wiki page](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Getting+user+confirmation) shows some approaches to doing this with Wicket, for assorted versions.

**EDIT:**

For your need of deciding logic based on the response, something using panel replacement as in the last approach (labeled **Without Javascript**) on the page referenced above is likely best.  There really is JavaScript involved in the panel replacement of course, but it's all supplied by Wicket and not coded by you...

Basically, you change your submit link so that instead of submitting, it replaces a panel containing your form with a new panel for the confirmation decision, and in that panel you have cancel and confirm links that do different things.

Another possibility is the approach shown in [this Wicket by Example article on ajax modal window confirms](http://wicketbyexample.com/wicket-ajax-confirmation-modal-window/).

Comment: Here showing just confirmation is not an issue for me . i want to receive some flag as per my code above from the script in java . and then based on that value i have to process the next logic which i am not getting as how to do

Comment: Thanks Don for your consistent help ... i have used this this Wicket by Example article on ajax modal window confirms. and it does work correctly as what i want except one simple issue ... its tough to put in words the issue however i do try step wise as below   1. i have a jsp page 2.on this jsp we call a wicket modal page using iframe source 3. again on this iframe which consists a wicket modal page i am calling a confirmation pop up .

Comment: . The issue here i am getting is once the confirmation popup comes the iframe window do not gets fully grayed. the outer thin border remains active for any action around the boundry of iframe i want that also to disable so that the user cant take any action from the confirmation pop up to iframe (parent for confirmation) . this is not the case if we use the javascript solution .however again in the javascript solution i need first the validation in script which gives some response in java then i can use if .. else to perform next save logic as per my first comment for code part .

Comment: Mixing jsp, wicket and iframe in this way sounds risky, and I don't know how to give further help without at least seeing some of that code.

Comment: That wiki page does not exist anymore :(